# Discontinuity of integral on noncompact product?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there an example of a continuous function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that for each $y_0$, $f(x,y_0)$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function of $x$, but the function $y \mapsto \int f(x,y) dx$ is not continuous?

I can prove it *is* continuous if $\mathbb R^2$ is replaced by a product of compact measure spaces. I suspect a counterexample can be given for the $\mathbb R^2$ case by exploiting something about non-interchange of limits.  I would prefer a counterexample as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the counterexample $f: [0,\infty)\times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ where

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x^3y}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2y}}, &x>0, y>0 \\0,&x\cdot y = 0 \end{cases}$$

We have $\lim_{y \to 0+} f(x,y) = 0$ and for $y > 0$

$$\int_0^\infty f(x,y) \, dx = \left.\frac{1}{2}e^{- \frac{1}{x^2y}}\right|_0^{\infty}= \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{y \to 0+}\int_0^\infty f(x,y) \, dx= \frac{1}{2}  \neq 0 = \int_0^\infty \lim_{y \to 0+}f(x,y) \, dx $$